# Get the generic type of a List in Groovy

Tags: groovy

I am building a automated swagger plugin. Here I run through annotated classes.

When we talk about the datatypes of String, Long, etc. is is enough for me use the simpleName method.

But when get to a Class of List, Set, Collection I need to know the generic type.

So how can I do this?

A example of code which do most of the job:

```
class Foo {
    List<String> myString
}

class SomeUtilClass {
    static String dataType(Class<?> c) {
        return c.simpleName
    }
    static List<String> dataTypes(Class<?> c) {
        return c.metaClass.properties.findAll {MetaProperty metaProperty ->
            metaProperty?.field != null
        }.collect {dataType(it.type)}

    }
}

SomeUtilClass.dataTypes(Foo) // ["List"] but I want something like ["List<String>"]
```

Comment: Since groovy is run on JVM: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3403909/get-generic-type-of-class-at-runtime

Comment: this question almost answer on my question but seems to be more runtime of new instances. I don't want check on the object.

Comment: Generics are erased at runtime at all. Not only on objects but on classes as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. I can look on the generic type from Cached fields.

See below example:

```
class SomeUtilClass {
    static String dataType(Class<?> c) {
        return c.simpleName
    }
    static List<String> dataTypes(Class<?> c) {
        return c.metaClass.properties.findAll {MetaProperty metaProperty ->
            metaProperty?.field != null
        }.collect {findGenerics(it.type)}

    }
    static void findGenerics(CachedField t) {
         t.field.genericType?.actualTypeArguments.collect {dataType(it)}
    }
}
```